# Reverse 32bit integer

Tags: python, integer, 32-bit

I'm trying to solve an exercie in [leetcode.com](https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-integer/#/description) which deals with `signed 32bit integers`.

The task is:

Return the inverse of a signed 32bit integer and return 0 if it overflows the 32bit signed integer's range.

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/32-bit):

> A 32-bit register can store 32 different values. The range of integer
>   values that can be stored in 32 bits depends on the integer
>   representation used. With the two most common representations, the
>   range is 0 through 4,294,967,295 (2^32 − 1) for representation as an
>   (unsigned) binary number, and −2,147,483,648 (−2^31) through
>   2,147,483,647 (2^31 − 1) for representation as two's complement.

So, if what i understood is correct i should test between the intervals `0 to (2^31)-1` and `(-2^31) to 0` otherwise, return `0`.

Here is my code:

```
def reverse_int(nums):
    a = str(nums)

    if 0 < nums <= (1 << 31)-1:
        return int(a[::-1])

    elif (-1 << 31) <= nums < 0:
        return -(int(a[:-len(a):-1]))
    else:
        return 0
```

Here is my problem: 
When i test my code on the website with:

```
nums = 1534236469 # Fail
nums = 1463847412 # Success
nums = 9000000    # Success
```

Why my current code fails with `1534236469` ? isn't `1534236469` in the range of `32 bit signed integers` ? What i'm missing ?

Comment: What output do you get for the case that fails?

Comment: For example, for `1534236469` on the website it should return 0. This means that `1534236469` overflows the range of 32 bit signed integers.

Comment: But it doesn't overflow.

Comment: In wikipedia they said `the two most common representations`. There is other representations of 32bit integers ?

Comment: You need to reverse then check if it overflows.

Comment: Steven is right. It goes beyond the range after you reverse it.

Comment: @StevenSummers add your comment as an answer i'll accept it.

Comment: This question explicitly says no 64-bit integers are allowed, and I believe it implicitly suggests that we don't use strings. 2 ** 31 has 10 digits, and uses 10 bytes. Meanwhile, a 64-bit integer only uses 8 bytes.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you must **first reverse** and then check. However here's a different way of checking.

To check you can just `&` the result with the appropriate mask.

So in your case the limits are `−2,147,483,648` and `2,147,483,647` the hex values of them are `-0x80000000` and `0x7fffffff`

Try this in the interpreter.

```
>>> 0x7fffffff
2147483647
>>> 2147483647 & 0x7fffffff   #within limit
2147483647
```

Values exceeding the limit, you can see some other value is displayed.

```
>>> 2147483648 & 0x7fffffff     #Exceeds limit
0
>>> 98989898989898 & 0x7fffffff  #Exceeds limit
1640235338
```

But when the value is within limit. The value is given as output.

```
>>> 1 & 0x7fffffff               #within limit
1
>>> 780 & 0x7fffffff
780
```

For negative values

```
 >>> -0x80000000     #Limit
-2147483648
>>> -2147483648 & -0x80000000
-2147483648
```

When the value is within the range. The **limit** is given as output.

```
>>> -2147483647 & -0x80000000
-2147483648
>>> -2 & -0x80000000          #within limit
-2147483648
>>> -2323 & -0x80000000
-2147483648
```

However if value is out of range you can see some other value is displayed.

```
>>> -2147483649 & -0x80000000
-4294967296
>>> -999999999999 & -0x80000000
-1000727379968
```

You can make use of this well and good to get what you want!

Here is a program that does what you want.

```
def reverse(x):
    str_x = str(x)
    if x<0:
        str_x = '-'+str_x[::-1][:-1]
        x = int(str_x)
    else:
        str_x = str_x[::-1]
        x = int(str_x)
    neg_limit= -0x80000000
    pos_limit= 0x7fffffff

    if(x<0):
        val=x&neg_limit
        if(val==neg_limit):
            return x
        else:
            return 0
    elif(x==0):
        return x
    else:
        val = x&pos_limit
        if(val==x):
            return x
        else:
            return 0

value = int(input("Enter value: "))
print(reverse(value))
```

The part below just reverses for both negative and positive values.

```
if x<0:
    str_x = '-'+str_x[::-1][:-1]
    x = int(str_x)
    print(x)
else:
    str_x = str_x[::-1]
    x = int(str_x)
    print(x)
```

Set the limits  `neg_limit= -0x80000000` and `pos_limit= 0x7fffffff` and check for them according to the explained logic.

Comment: Or, in a much simpler way compare the reversed `int` of `str_x` if it's between `(-1 << 31)` and  `(1 << 31)-1`. If not return `0`. By the way your approach is correct too, but too verbose.

Comment: Yes it is but wanted to mention the use of `&` and using a `mask`

Answer (score 2):

The solution is already there, I am posting this because this might be helpful for newbies like me. I used the **void's** solution (above) to make it complete. At first, I did the testing without performing the reverse method, it was showing the problem as mentioned in the original question. Then I did the test after reversing the numbers in both positive and negative case and it worked.

```
def reverse(self, x: int) -> int:
        neg_limit =-0x80000000 # hex(-2**31-1),see details in accepted answer above
        pos_limit = 0x7fffffff #hex(2**31-1)
        if x >0:
            reverse_num = int(str(x)[::-1])
            if reverse_num & pos_limit==reverse_num: #conditions explained above
                return reverse_num
            else:
                return 0

        elif x <0:
            reverse_num = -int(str(abs(x))[::-1])
            if reverse_num&neg_limit == neg_limit:
                return reverse_num
            else:
                    return 0
        else:
            return 0
```

Answer (score 1):

This happen because nums = 1534236469 is in the range of 32 bit signed integer, but it's reverse  9646324351 is not in the range of 32 bit signed integer.

```
class Solution:
def reverse(self, x: int) -> int:
    if x in range((-1 << 31),(1 << 31)-1):
        r=0
        c=False
        if(x<0):
            c=True
            x*=-1

        while(x!=0):
            r=10*r+x%10
            x=x//10
        if(c):
            r*=-1
        if r in range((-1 << 31),(1 << 31)-1):
            return r
        else:
            return 0
    else:
        return 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple and pure mathematical -

```
def reverse(self, x: int) -> int:
        r = 2 ** 31
        maxLimit = r - 1
        minLimit = r * -1
        rev = None
        negative = False

        if x < 0:
            negative = True
            x = x * -1

        while True:
            mod = x % 10
            x = (x - mod) / 10

            if not rev:
                rev = mod
            else:
                rev = (rev * 10) + mod

            if x <= 0:
                break

        if negative:
            rev = rev * -1

        returnValue = int(rev)
        if returnValue < minLimit or returnValue > maxLimit:
            return 0 #Return whatever you want. if overflows
        return int(rev)
```

Comment: Nice mathematical way to think. I rewrote this in a more pythonic way. The statement `rev * 10 + mod` can cause overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, mathematical and pythonic way based on @Keshari's solution

```py
def reverse(x):
    is_neg = x < 0
    imax = (1 << 31) - 1
    imin = (-1 << 31)
    r = 0
    x = abs(x)
    while x:
        x, m = divmod(x, 10)
        if (r > imax / 10) or (r == imax / 10 and m > 7):
            return 0
        if (r < imin / 10) or (r == imin / 10 and m < -8):
            return 0
        r = (r * 10) + m
    return r * -1 if is_neg else r
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of checking the overflow of the result without using any additional variables for limits is this:

```
def reverse(x):
    num = str(abs(x))

    if x < 0:
        result = -1 * int(num[::-1])
    else:
        result = int(num[::-1])

    if result not in range((-1 << 31), (1 << 31) - 1):
        return 0

    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Reverse signed integer, but return 0 if outside int32 limits given as below 2^31 or above 2^31 -1.

[Embedding it in the solution class is part the problem site requirement.]

I am new to Python so please criticize -- in fact this is my first Python function and first 'class'.

It seems easy and clear to do the following:

```
class Solution:
    def reverse(self, x: int) -> int:
        s = str(abs(x))[::-1]
        sign = -1 if x < 0 else 1
        rx = int(s) * sign
        return 0 if rx < -2**31 or rx > 2**31 - 1 else rx
```

Collapsing out the temporary values s, rx, and/or sign is easy too but doesn't makes is less clear.

Seriously I'd appreciate criticism as this is literally my first Python; been meaning to learn it for years.